# DidSelect highlight changing view color is not working

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have one collection view, where in each cell i have one background view. So whenever user select any cell that particular cell view background  color will change.

But now the problem is its background color is changing...but if i select another cell the previous selected cell view background color should be change to normal color.That is not happening.

the previous cell view background  color also still as selected state

here is my vc `didselectmethod` :

```
let cell = chartCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? UserDataVC
var data = [String: Any]()
data["selectedCell"] = true
cell?.set(dataSource: data)
```

my collectionview cell :

```
class userCell: CollectionViewCell {

   override func set(data: [String : AnyObject]) {

  if let selectedCell = data["selectedCell"] as? Bool {
            if selectedCell { 
                mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }

     }
}
```

Any solution would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

What's `mainView`?
You should generally change either the cell's `contentView` or assign a `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` to a cell.
Additionally and a bit unrelated, I would use a different method for changing content in response to events:
I would never change a cell directly by down casting it.
Instead, I would change the data I use to initialize the cells, and then reload the cells I want to change, and then re-create (actually, it would probably be re-used) the cells as needed using `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`.
This way, you never need to down cast.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is very poor.
I'd suggest saving the highlighted cell's index as a property, and accessing it to highlight or unhighlight when it dequeues.  For example:

```
// Your CollectionView Delegate class
var currentHighlightedCellIndex: Int?
```

Then in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`:

```
// Dequeue the cell
... 

if let selectedIndex = self.currentHighlightedCellIndex, selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
    cell.selectedCell = true
} else {
    cell.selectedCell = false 
}

// Return the cell
...
```

In your `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCustomCellClass else { fatalError() }

cell.selectedCell = true
if let previouslySelectedIndex = self.currentHighlightedCellIndex {
    // Here we get the index paths for each visible cell and check wether it's selected.
    let indexPaths = collectionView.visibleCells.compactMap { collectionView.indexPath(for: $0) }
    for index in (indexPaths.map { $0.item }) {
        if index == previouslySelectedIndex {
            // We found a cell that is highlighted and visible, get it in deselect it.
            guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)) else { fatalError() }
            cell.selectedCell = false
        }
    }
}

self.currentHighlightedCellIndex = indexPath.item
```

You can set an observed property in your custom collection view cell class that will control the background color, like so:

```
// Custom cell class
var selectedCell: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        self.mainView.backgroundColor = selectedCell ? .red : .white
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to pass the datasource and i need to handle that in my collection view level.is it possible . with my didselect code logic ?

Comment: @teja What do you mean by "you need to pass the datasource"?

Comment: I really can't see how this answers the question. While the coding methods of the author are questionable, the question is still somewhat valid, and your answer is all about how to keep track of the highlighted cell, and does not relate to the matter at hand. Additionally - there is no guarantee a cell does not persist even if it's not visible (it happens to work this way but it's not documented), so in theory and in future iOS versions - there may be additional cells that retain this property. A different approach would have been to reload the previously selected cell as well as the new cell.

Comment: @Eilon if user select the cell, i am highlighting in didselectmethod itself. Like this `let cell = chartCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? userCELL
        cell?.mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: but still the previous selected cell is still highlighted.i need to highlight the cell which i am selecting

Comment: @MosheGottlieb To my understanding, OP's task is pretty simple, highlight a cell visually as it's selected, and unhighlight any other selected cells if there are any. I couldn't figure out his attempt to implement this behavior, so I offered an alternative solution which is better in my view.